# Jquery Select2 Load ajax data on page load

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using a jquery select2 plugin, i have this setup `brands.js`:

```
$('.select2').select2({
    ajax: {
        url: '/data/brands-get',
        dataType: 'json',
        placeholder: "Проивзодитель...",
        allowClear: true

    }
});
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#select2-add').trigger("change");
});
```

in the `brands.php` view:

```
echo $form->field($model, 'brand_name', ['template' => '{label}{input}{error}'])
->dropDownList(array(), ['class' => 'form-control select2','id' =>'select2-add'])->label("Brand",["class" => ""]);
```

Under the `/data/brands-get` i have a yii2 action, which returns json of the brands, and returns selected brand by the current user, by looking up in the mysql database. The problem is, when i load the page, `/brands` the view renders select and everything ok, if i click on the select-add, i get the correct behaviour, search is working etc, but there is no ajax request made on page load, to fill `select2` with data, and set default item! I added this:
`$('#select2-add').trigger("change");` but this doesn't work, there is no request made on page load to `/data/brands-get`. How can i trigget the loading of items on select2 on page load??

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so there is no simple thing like `$('.select2').reload()` so i did this:

```
function getFilters(element)
{
    $.ajax({
        url    : "/data/brands-get",
        type   : 'GET',
        data   : "",
        timeout : 10000,
        success: function (response)
        {
            for(var i =0; i < response.results.length; i++){
                var newOption = new Option(response.results[i].text, response.results[i].id, false, false);
                $(element).append(newOption).trigger('change');
            }
        },
        error  : function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
        {

            alert("error");

        }
    });

}
$( document ).ready(function() {

   getFilters("#brand-add");
});
```

Just manually added the options to the select element on load.