# Automatically select the option in jquery select2, if only one option is present in dropdown, without clicking it, on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have written the following `select2` code:

```
$('#dropdownElem').select2({
    placeholder: 'Select From Dropdown',
    allowClear: true,
    ajax: {
        quietMillis: 10,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
        url: function(){
          return '/api/'
        },
        data: function (params) {
            return {
              model__icontains: params.term
            };
        },
        processResults: function(data) {
          if (data['modelDocs'].length == 1) {
              $("#dropdownElem").append($("<option />")
                  .attr("value", data['modelDocs'][0].id)
                  .html(data['modelDocs'][0].text)
              ).val(data['modelDocs'][0].id).trigger("change");
          }
          return {
            results: $.map(data['modelDocs'], function(obj) {
              return {
                id: obj.id,
                text: obj.modelDoc
              };
            })
          };
        },
    },
});

$('#dropdownElem').trigger("change.select2");
```

Now what I want to do is if the options returned by ajax call are only one then I should make that option selected automatically and if it is greater than one then the user can select the required by clicking.
For a single option I want it to be selected automatically without clicking. When I console logged the `processResults` it is being called only on clicking the dropdown and not on loading the page widget where this dropdown is shown.
How can I get the desired result?

Comment: According to the [transforming-response-data documentation](https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax#transforming-response-data) `processResults:` is the correct place to transform the results - this will be called *after* the ajax request - but the ajax request will not be called until you activate the drop down - so you're looking in the wrong place (in your question, but the title looks like the correct idea - maybe update the question to match the title?)

Comment: There's also this suggestion from `select2` which appears to be suggesting you simply make an initial ajax call on load to pre-populate your drop down:  [Preselecting options in an(sic) remotely-sourced (AJAX) Select2](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items#preselecting-options-in-an-remotely-sourced-ajax-select2)

Comment: Same question, but not really a useful answer (just says "can't do it") https://stackoverflow.com/a/51129262/2181514

Comment: Yes. I missed `$` while typing.

Comment: So based on your second comment I guess I should trigger click and then select the option and then close the dropdown if I am not wrong.

Comment: I have changed the title. I dont know if it can be done, based on your fourth comment.

Comment: So if the issue is that you open the select2, wait for ajax, then there's only 1 so you want it auto-clicked - shouldn't be an issue.   I was trying to find a way to pre-load the data via ajax when the select2 is initialised, which is a different issue :)

Comment: Actually I was looking for a way to call that ajax call itself but for my present problem I want what I have mentioned to be done automatically on page load. Trigger the dropdown and then select the only option if there is one and then close the dropdown and that selected option should be visible. All done automatically once my widget loads.

Comment: So you *do* want it to auto-ajax call on loading/init of the select2?   Your question no longer indicates that.

Comment: I was thinking that if I trigger a click event automatically on this dropdown then the select2 dropdown will be called and therefore the ajax and its other methods. Then do a select operation if it exists and then close.

Answer (score 1):

Since I could not find a way to trigger `click` on `select2` on page load, my solution was to add these lines on page load or whenever the widget containing that `select2` is called in a function:

```
$('#dropdownElem').select2('open');
$('#dropdownElem').select2('close');
```

So since I am checking the length of options in `processResults`, I had to trigger click and close functionality on the dropdown.
`select2` has methods `open` and `close` to replicate almost the same for my use case.